# Has Floating point theory of Z3 supported in C++ API

Tags: c++, api, floating-point, z3

From RELEASE_NOTES of the latest version of Z3, Z3-4.4.1, it has supported for floating point theory. And I have tested that in offline way successfully. However, in my current project, Z3 needs to be used in C++ API, after reading related document and source code, I haven't find any API function for floating point theory. Has  Floating point theory of Z3 supported in  C++ API ？

Nevertheless, maybe I can write my constraints set to a smt format file, then  use Z3 API to parse this file. But, it is my last choose to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ API is essentially a wrapper around the C API for common idioms, e.g., to automatize reference counting. The two can and should be used together though. For instance, the [C-API example](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp#L238) shows how to create a bit-vector signed remainder term (for which there is no C++ function) via a call to the C function `Z3_mk_bvsrem`. The same trick applies to all floating-point terms; just create them via the respective C functions and then save them in a (C++) `z3::expr` object.

Comment: Thanks, @Christoph.****** "The same trick applies to all floating-point terms; just create them via the respective C functions " *******. It doesn't matter with C API or C++ API.  After all, I can write with the combination of C API and C++ API. Has it supported in C API, right? I will read the source code, any other document  or tutorial?

Comment: Yes, the floating-point functions are all available in the C-API. They are decared in z3_fpa.h and they have their own section called "Floating-Point API" in the [documentation](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html).